# a command inside a variable

Tags: ksh

I want to fill a variable with a commnad line read from a file and execute it. No problem when it is a single command. When I use a |, it doesn´t work. 
Any help ???
Thank you

```
$ f="ls -1"
$ $f
a
a0
a1
a2
a3
b1
cfg
cfile
dfile
e
fcorreo.txt
log
logs
work
$ f="ls -1 | tail -1"
$ $f
ls: cannot access |: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access tail: No such file or directory
$ f='ls -1 | tail -1'
$ $f
ls: cannot access |: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access tail: No such file or directory
$ echo $f
ls -1 | tail -1
```

Comment: Sorry ...$ f="ls -1"
$ $f
a
a0
a1
a2
a3
b1
cfg
cfile
dfile
e
fcorreo.txt
log
logs
work
$ f="ls -1 | tail -1"
$ $f
ls: cannot access |: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access tail: No such file or directory
$ f='ls -1 | tail -1'
$ $f
ls: cannot access |: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access tail: No such file or directory
$ echo $f
ls -1 | tail -1

Comment: Please have a look into the [formatting help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and update your question.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `eval` might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the pipe (`|`) is a "meta" command run by the shell, and it connects two different commands. So `ls -1 | tail -1` is running two commands (`ls` and `tail`) and uses a shell-construct (`|`) to connect to two.
(so your title ***a** command inside a variable* is incorrect, as your problem is really ***multiple** commands inside a **single** variable*)

Anyhow, the solution is to parse/exec your command with the shell:

```
f="ls -1 | tail -1"
sh -c "${f}"
```

Alternatively, you could also use `eval`, which works without forking a new shell process:

```
f="ls -1 | tail -1"
eval "${f}"
```

Comment: @teje But seriously, using a shell function would be safer. Also replacing `ls - 1` by `printf '%s\n' *` would ensure that characters that `ls` might replace by question marks are passed through properly.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a function as below;

```
f() { ls -1 | tail -1; }
```

Eg;

```
user@host $ f() { ls -1 | tail -1; }
user@host $ f
test.txt
```

Comment: @teje : I updated ans. this could help you.

Comment: @teje you should state your goal then (running two commands via a single variable is only a *means* to accomplish your goal; but it's unclear what you are trying to solve)